# ¿Porque cuando uso el método value.count() me da un dtype=int64 pero cuando uso .unique() dtype=object?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, dataframe

Me gustaría saber si esto es normal al correr los metodos value.count() y .unique() deberían ambos ser iguales? o es algo que no estoy entiendiendo? Igual cuando hago el .info() me dice que la variable de restaurant_name es un objeto lo cual es correcto debido que son nombres y son cadenas.

[image: codigo que estoy usando en google colab]

Answer (score 1):

**El tipo que te muestra al ejecutar `value_counts()` y `unique()` no es el tipo de los datos de tu dataframe/columna original, es el tipo de los datos de los objetos retornados por dichos métodos.**

`pandas.Series.unique` basicamente retorna un array de NumPy con los valores únicos (sin repetir) de tu columna, es decir, muestra un conjunto con todos los valores de la columna eliminando las repeticiones. Lógicamente el tipo del array de NumPy que retorna el método es el mismo tipo que el de los datos de tu columna, ya que son los mismos valores solo que eliminando los duplicados.

`pandas.Series.value_counts` retorna una nueva serie de Pandas con la cuenta de los valores únicos de tu columna. A grandes rasgos, aplica una funcion hash como `unique()` para obtener los valores sin repeticiones y luego usa estos elementos únicos para crear el índice de la nueva serie a retornar, asignando a cada uno como valor el numero de veces que aparecen en la columna (serie) original. Por lo tanto, la nueva serie retornada por el método tiene un índice con el mismo tipo de dato que el de tu columna, pero los valores de dicha serie van a ser siempre `int` independientemente del tipo de la serie sobre la que se aplica, ya que es un entero que representa el número de apariciones de cada valor.

Recuerda que el tipo de dato de un objeto `pandas.Series` se lo dan sus valores y no el índice, por eso el tipo es `int64` y no `Object` (el tipo del índice).

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"datos": ["B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B"]})
>>> df
  datos
0     B
1     A
2     C
3     B
4     A
5     B

>>> df["datos"].dtype
dtype('O')

>>> uniques = df["datos"].unique()
>>> uniques
array(['B', 'A', 'C'], dtype=object)

>>> type(uniques)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> uniques.dtype
dtype('O')

>>> count =  df["datos"].value_counts()
>>> count
datos
B    3
A    2
C    1
Name: count, dtype: int64

>>> type(count)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

>>> count.dtype
dtype('int64')

>>> count.index
Index(['B', 'A', 'C'], dtype='object', name='datos')
```